# android.database.sqliteSQLiteException no such table

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

please help me i have a problem with my database .

here is my code

```
    private static final String DB_TABLE = "create table personn (personId integer primary key autoincrement, "+ "personName text not null, personAge text not null, "+ " personName text not null, " + " photoId text not null);";
```

and + this :

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL(DB_TABLE);

}
```

but while i want to insert or select th android gives me error :

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: persons (code
>   1): , while compiling: SELECT personName, photoId, personAge FROM
>   persons

Comment: that means your table is not created, remove semicolon from last in DBtable variable.

Comment: i try that to it dosent work

Comment: and your table name is different, use same table name for creating and selecting.

Comment: After making the change(s) (correct the table name) you will need to either clear/delete the App's data or uninstall the App and then restart the App. In short the `onCreate` method only runs when the database is initially created.

Answer (score 1):

You have made a spelling mistake while creating the person table. You have named it as "personn" instead of "persons".

Comment: i try that too doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite clear - there is no table named person**s**. Either fix your select to reference person**n** or your create statement to create a table named person**s**.